# gcc and llvm linux shutdown function from c code

Tags: c, linux, gcc, system-calls, llvm-gcc

Linux x86-64 compiling and statically linking with gcc I have:

```
#include <sys/reboot.h>

if (str[0] == 'r')
  reboot(0x1234567);
```

but I can't seem to find the equivalent function call for shutdown. I'd also like to know the llvm function if different.

Comment: Check the documentation. http://linux.die.net/man/2/reboot . However, only call reboot() if you really, really know what you're doing - it does an unsafe shutown/reboot of your system - you'd have to defer to the /sbin/shutdown or /sbin/reboot command to do it safely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `sys/reboot.h` :

```
/* Perform a hard reset now.  */
#define RB_AUTOBOOT     0x01234567

[...]

/* Stop system and switch power off if possible.  */
#define RB_POWER_OFF    0x4321fedc
```

So `reboot(0x4321fedc);` or `reboot(RB_POWER_OFF);` should work.

Comment: Ah so Shutdown is a special case of Reboot. Maybe because I started out as a windows user, I think of Reboot as being a special case of Shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
system("shutdown -h now");
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. The only things I have on the system are the kernel in the /boot directory and my statically compiled init file in the /sbin directory.